# Django + jQuery - Create Placeholders from database field value

Tags: javascript, django

I have this form:

---

```
  <form method="POST" id="my_form" autocomplete="off"> {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

---

`{{ field.label_tag }}` renders this `label`:

```
    <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
```

`{{ field }}` renders this `input`field:

```
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="20" required="" id="id_name">
```

---

Unfortunately, there are no placeholders, so I created them by myself:

---

```
$(".form-group").each(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').attr("placeholder", "placeholder");
});
```

---

The placeholders show up, now I want to populate them with the corresponding values from the database.

---

Example:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
```

placeholder = Julia

What would be the best approach to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to added placeholder only then try adding this code in

form
This is example add your key as example like as password.

```
password = forms.CharField(label='password',widget=forms.PasswordInput((attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'})))
```

or 
Try this.

```
class Meta:
        model = MyModel
widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter description here'}),
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an invalid syntax error. The error is pointing to: `((attrs={`

Comment: It is `(attrs={` and not `((attrs={` anyway I want the placeholders to contain the values from the database and not the keys.

Comment: Ohh that's good then your approach is good i think.But change your heading then placeholder from database.

Comment: I don't have an approach - that's why I am asking. The only way I could think of would work, is to iterate over the model's fields like `{% for names in model %} {{ name }} {% endfor %}` and map each name to a placeholder, but there is for sure a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a default value instead of a placeholder now, you could use the `default` argument in the model field.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, default='some_default')
```

Then I believe the model form will pull this through as the initial form value for the corresponding field automatically.

Comment: That's great, but I want the placeholders to update each time new data gets stored into the database, so that the user knows what values have been saved previously